# Node installs with the wrong version of NPM

Tags: node.js, npm

**Hey guys, I previously posted this question but with no reply. I'm posting again to hopefully get some much needed answers.**

I'm following a tutorial for NodeJS. In the tutorial, it says "install this version of npm to follow along" which i did, and it was version 5.5.1.

Unfortunately, the version wasn't compatible with my node version so I tried to upgrade my npm but it wouldn't work either. So most posts say to re-install Node which I did, but I still get the following error:

```
C:\Users\Admin>npm install npm@latest -g
npm WARN npm npm does not support Node.js v12.18.1
npm WARN npm You should probably upgrade to a newer version of node as we
npm WARN npm can't make any promises that npm will work with this version.
npm WARN npm Supported releases of Node.js are the latest release of 4, 6, 7, 8.
npm WARN npm You can find the latest version at https://nodejs.org/
WARNING: You are likely using a version of node-tar or npm that is incompatible with this version of 
Node.js.
Please use either the version of npm that is bundled with Node.js, or a version of npm (> 5.5.1 or < 
5.4.0) or node-tar (> 4.0.1) that is compatible with Node.js 9 and above.
npm[7656]: c:\ws\src\node_zlib.cc:575: Assertion `args.Length() == 7 && "init(windowBits, level, 
memLevel, strategy, writeResult, writeCallback," " dictionary)"' failed.
```

Also for some reason, `npm -v` still displays 5.5.1.  And I don't think Node 12.8.1 comes with NPM 5.5.1. So maybe that over-written upgrade I did is still there?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you had installed npm along then uninstall it and install nvm.
Using nvm you can install any version of node and also you can install multiple versions of the node. you can switch any version of the node as per your requirements.

Here is the ref link for install nvm.
https://codeburst.io/nvm-for-windows-how-to-install-and-use-13b7a4209791

Comment: But I don't need to change my node version, or need multiple node versions. I just need my NPM to match my Node. Is there a way to install NPM independent of Node?

Comment: I know you don't want to change node version, but once you have done what I mentioned above, it will be very helpful to you and you will get rid of this version mismatching issue.

Comment: Okay I will try it now, thank you for your patience.

Comment: Fixed it. I deleted two npm folders from appdata folder which I think were there from when I was using react-native. Thank you though. I give +1

Answer (score 0):

for upgrading npm try with sudo  :

```
sudo npm install -g npm@latest
```

for upgrading nodejs with npm try this :

```
sudo npm install -g n 

sudo n latest
```

this question is **duplicate**

Comment: Both commands require npm to be working :) Npm is not working. Question is not duplicate.